# Node.js - Uploading both an image and a file with Multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I am working on a mod site, and I was able to create a method that uploads an image, but I was wondering if it's possible to also upload a zip file in the same method. I tried chaining on code for the file after creating a file model, but I get an unexpected field error. Here's the method I'm trying

```
router.post('/upload', uploadImage.single('image'), uploadFile.single('file'), IsLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    var newImg = new Image({
        data: req.file.filename
    });

    var newFile = new File({
        data: req.file.filename
    });

    Mod.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        image: newImg.data,
        game: req.body.game,
        file: newFile.data
    }, (err, newMod) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/mods');
        }
    });
});
```

And here are my storage engines

```
const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './public/images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './public/images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const uploadImage = multer({storage: imageStorage});
const uploadFile = multer({storage: fileStorage});
```

Is it possible to use 2 storage engines and chain 2 uploads in one method, or am I going about it all wrong? Any clarification or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think you can use multiple `single()` since they'll both try to set `req.file`

Comment: Ok, thanks for responding. Looks like I'll have to find a smooth way to do it in 2 different methods then, eh?